# How can I pick data out of an array in a object and insert it into another array in an object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have variable qstore that's has an ans array containing a list of responses. The field named r is used to hold the response data (true or false) and is stored in an array called `ans`

```
qstore: {"id":2,
         "qId":2,
         "ans":[{"r":true},
                {"r":true},
                {"r":false},
                {"r":false},
                {"r":false}]}
```

Another variable qview:

```
qview: {"problemId":2,
          "questionId":1,
          "answer":null,
          "text":"xx",
          "answers":[{"answerId":1,
                      "response":false},
                     {"answerId":2,
                      "response":false},
                     {"answerId":3,
                      "response":false},
                     {"answerId":4,
                      "response":false},
                     {"answerId":5,
                       "response":false}]}
```

What I need to do is IF there is an array called `ans` in qstore (there may not be one) then I need to take the answer responses field `r` and use that to update the answers `response` field in the qview object. Note that the qview and qstore if they do have answers will always have the same number of answers.

Can anyone tell me a simple way that I can do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript has an multiple ways to check if a key exists in an object: `in` and  `Object.hasOwnProperty`. The difference between the two is that `in` also returns `true` if the key is found in the prototype chain of your object.

Now it appears the id's of your response are 1-indexed, but that doesn't matter if we iterate over the index of its position in the array itself:

```
if ('ans' in qstore) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= qstore.ans.length; i++) {
        qview.answers[[i].response = qstore.ans[i].r
    }
}
```

There's also a nicer `forEach` available, if you're not expecting to support IE8 and earlier, or are prepared to insert a "shim":

```
if ('ans' in qstore) {
    qstore.ans.forEach(function(element, index) {
        element.response = qstore.ans[index].r
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jackie. I like the way you suggest using forEach. That's a lot easier for me.

Comment: And if the "ans" array exists and is empty? maybe a verification is more viable.

Comment: @PauloRoberto The loop is executed as many times as there are elements . So for an empty array nothing would happen. If you want a special action when the array is empty, a simple validation (e.g. `if  (qstore.ans.length === 0) { // do something }`) would indeed suffice.

Answer (score 3):

> What I need to do is IF there is an array called ans in qstore (there may not be one) then I need to take the answer responses field r and use that to update the answers response field in the qview object. Note that the qview and qstore if they do have answers will always have the same number of answers.

```
// assuming `qstore`, `qview`
var i, j, ans = qstore.ans;
if (ans) { // if qstore has non-falsy ans
    qstore: for (i = 0, j = 0; i < ans.length; ++i) { // loop over ans
        for (; j < qview.answers.length; ++j) { // look in qview
            if (qview.answers[j].answerId === i + 1) { // qview has already
                qview.answers[j].response = ans[i].r;
                continue qstore; // go back to looping ans
            } else if (qview.answers[j].answerId <= i) { // qview needs new
                break; // get out of qview loop
            }
        } // if we reach here then qview didn't have an entry for this item
        qview.answers.splice(j, 0, { // insert new entry
            'answerId': i + 1,
            'response': ans[i].r
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: omg how did you read the whole question, think, and write that code in less than 8 mins?

Comment: Fixed it, forgot a `.length` :P

Answer (score 2):

Just simply loop over the `qstore.ans` array (if it exists) and set the respective value in `qview`.

```
if(qstore.hasOwnProperty('ans')){
    for(var i = 0, len = qstore.ans.length; i < len; i++){
        qview.answers[i].response = qstore.ans[i].r;
    }
}
```

Comment: `qstore.hasOwnProperty('ans')` will return true even if `ans` have 0 registers, so why execute the code if you have 0 registers?

Comment: @PauloRoberto: Because running a `for` loop on a blank array doesn't use that much CPU time that I need to worry about it.

Comment: heh, well ok but that's a additional verification for optimization :P

Answer (score 1):

**The most simple solution.**

**This way it will execute only if you have at less, 1 register on `ans` array**, i see that the solutions above do not verify if the `ans` array have registers, so i think it is the right one for your case.

Here is the code:

```
if (qstore.ans != null){
    if (qstore.ans.length > 0){
        for (i=0;i<qstore.ans.length);i++){
            qview.answers[i].response = qstore.ans[i].r;
        }
    }
}
```